# Marshmallow Joined Schemas for SQLAlchemy joined result

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, schema, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I am having some trouble to get marshmallow dumping correctly a join query result with a proper defined Schema.

What I used so far is a NestedSchema but this only works when I am querying a single Model/Table with a relationship. (this relationship data is automatically added to the row when the query is performed)

```
class JoinSchema(mm.Schema):
    class Meta:
        json_module = simplejson
    table1 = fields.Nested(Table1Schema, many=False)
    table2= fields.Nested(Table2Schema, many=False)
```

I use simplejson to map Decimal objects properly

Here's the query I am trying to map:

```
db.session.query(Table1, Table2)\
            .join(Table2) \
            .filter(Table1.column1 == value1) \
            .filter(Table1.column2 == value2) \
            .filter(Table1.column3.contains(value3) \
            .all()
```

Thanks in advance.